# xslt create ordered list from string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Have a string in xml

```
<anons>
      1. first list item. 2. second list item. 3. third list item.
</anons>
```

Is it possible to create an ordered list like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>first list item.</li>
  <li>second list item.</li>
  <li>third list item.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please do not tag questions with both `xslt-1.0` and `xslt-2.0` - they exclude each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but it would have to be a string operation, meaning it might not be possible in some cases if the text is more complex than this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="anons">
    <ol>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize (./string(), '\d+\.')[normalize-space()]">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="anons">
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '[0-9]+\.')[normalize-space()]">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

you should get what you want. Another option would be to use `analyze-string`.