# Ways to parse out values inside of xml nodes and print them in additional xml nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering what might be a good way to approach this issue. I have to clean up ~1000 xml files that have multiple names within one name tag. Further complicating the issue, there is no distinction between first and last name.

Basically what I have is this:

```
<name>Li, S.; Wang, K.; Wang, D.</name>
```

and what I want is this:

```
<name>
 <given>S.</given>
 <family>Li</family>
</name>
```

and so on, for the other names. It doesn't seem like XSLT is really intended to separate out values in this way but I could be wrong. Is there a way that I can do this? Any language is fine, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Is your XSL processor 1.0 or 2.0?  If 1.0, do you have support for the EXSLT strings extension? If the answer to either of these is "yes", look for a string function called "tokenize".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar question was asked today and you can find the answer to you question here:

[xslt create ordered list from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764301/xslt-create-ordered-list-from-string/28764478#28764478)

EDIT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <names>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize (., '; ')[normalize-space()]">
            <name>
                <given><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ', ')"/></given>
                <family><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ', ')"/></family> 
            </name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </names>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<names>
  <name>
    <given>S.</given>
    <family>Li</family>
  </name>
  <name>
    <given>K.</given>
    <family>Wang</family>
  </name>
  <name>
    <given>D.</given>
    <family>Wang</family>
  </name>
</names>
```